# "Auto-property accessor is never used" warning from ReSharper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resharper-8.0

Our Application is an MVC Application .  I tried to run code analysis using ReSharper.  I am getting "Auto-property accessor is never used" as warnings in many of my view model properties.

For example, ReSharper shows the warning on this:

```
public bool IsLegalEntry { get; set; }
```

Can I make a private setter, or can anybody suggest an alternative?

Comment: `public bool IsLegalEntry { get; private set; }`

Comment: @Андрей that will hide the warning but break the application. MVC's models need publicly-writable properties. Making the setter private is not the solution here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790597/resharper-warnings-with-mvvm

Comment: Yeah thanks for the reply. So thats the confusion. If we tried to solve the warning it may affect the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resharper Warnings with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790597/resharper-warnings-with-mvvm)

Answer (score 8):

You could make the setter private

```
public bool IsLegalEntry { get; private set; }
```

However, this could cause a runtime error if the setter is used implicitly.  Alternatively you could decorate the setter with the `JetBrains.Annotations.UsedImplicitlyAttribute`.

```
public bool IsLegalEntry { get; [UsedImplicitly] set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to "warning fixing/suppressing" paradigm, you can add testing project to your solution. Then write a test for you business logic **hitting the accessor(s) in question** among other things.

Not sure this is the action you were looking for, however

- it provides the **effect** you were after
- saves for redundant annotation attributes
- adds testing bonus

Comment: Be careful not to add tests that don't add value just to suppress a warning. Testing that calling get on a auto property after calling set for the same auto property is pretty useless and just adds cruft to your project.

Comment: @Steven Writing agree with the sentiment. However writing tests around models can be useful, especially to test the contract but there is the rub. If you want to test the contract you do not want to test by deserializing back into the model but you want to test the raw serialized data. This is because any refactor to the model could potentially break the contract but still allow the tests to pass if just doing assertions on the deserialized model. Whilst this is a good practice it wouldn't be any use to solve the OP problem.